# Benefits of runtime.LockOSThread in Golang

Tags: go

Golang supports [`LockOSThread()`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#LockOSThread) to make current goroutine exclusively tied to current OS thread, and it can also [`UnlockOSThread()`](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#UnlockOSThread).

Are there any use cases that benefit from this feature?

Comment: Let's say you have 8 processor threads and 16 goroutines. This means that there are on average two goroutines per real thread. Now if you're building something real-time, you want to be able to run code as soon as possible and avoid the matching of goroutines to threads, you don't want your real time code to get 'behind' less important code. This can solve priority inversion problems etc. Although schedular activations can mitigate this.

Comment: A good example of using this function can be found in http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/lookup_windows.go . I'd recommend doing a google search for "lockosthread site:golang.org/src/pkg/".

Comment: the examples are great, thanks @Intermernet

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the Go threading model, calls to C code, assembler code, or blocking system calls occur in the same thread as the calling Go code, which is managed by the Go runtime scheduler.

The `os.LockOSThread()` mechanism is mostly useful when Go has to interface with some foreign library (a C library for instance). It guarantees that several successive calls to this library will be done in the same thread.

This is interesting in several situations:

- a number of [graphic libraries](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/LockOSThread) (OS X Cocoa, OpenGL, SDL, ...) require all the calls to be done on a specific thread (or the main thread in some cases).
- some foreign libraries are based on [thread local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (TLS) facilities. They store some context in a data structure attached to the thread. Or some functions of the API provide results whose memory lifecycle is attached to the thread. This concept is used in both Windows and Unix-like systems. A typical example is the errno global variable commonly used in C libraries to store error codes. On systems supporting multi-threading, [errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) is generally defined as a thread-local variable.
- more generally, some foreign libraries may use a thread identifier to index/manage internal resources.

Comment: Great summary!! It also gives me ideas about how to optimise CGO wrapped Clib calls, exactly what I needed. Thx

Comment: Hmm, some further discussion about optimising Cgo call or not on Gonuts at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/VB_9P29X040 (After knowing more about the internal, my idea above may not help on Cgo performance.)

Comment: Also very good article describing how the scheduler works.
http://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler

Comment: Important to add, doing any sort of linux namespace switch (e.g. unsharing a network or process namespace) is also bound to a thread, so if you don't lock the OS thread before you might get part of your code randomly scheduled into a different network/process namespace.

Comment: Some syscalls may depend on os thread. For example, ptrace only works if called from the same thread where it has been inited.

Answer (score 6):

[runtime.LockOsThread](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#LockOSThread) it is usually used for calling C code that requires running in the main thread, like in graphics libraries.

Go Wiki [page](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/LockOSThread) about LockOsThread and an example on how to use it.

Google groups [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/IiWZ2hUuLDA/SNKYYZBelsYJ) about the use of LockOsThread in SDL.

Answer (score 5):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378536/6309), What `runtime.LockOSThread` does is prevent any other goroutine from running on the same thread.
But note that [Go 1.10 (Q1 2018)](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.10#runtime) will change its usage a bit:

> Because one common use of `LockOSThread` and `UnlockOSThread` is to allow Go code to reliably modify thread-local state (for example, Linux or Plan 9 name spaces), the runtime now treats locked threads as unsuitable for reuse or for creating new threads.
>
> The behavior of nested calls to `LockOSThread` and `UnlockOSThread` has changed. These functions control whether a goroutine is locked to a specific operating system thread, so that the goroutine only runs on that thread, and the thread only runs that goroutine.
>
> Previously, calling `LockOSThread` more than once in a row was equivalent to calling it once, and a single `UnlockOSThread` always unlocked the thread.
>
> Now, the calls nest: if `LockOSThread` is called multiple times, `UnlockOSThread` must be called the same number of times in order to unlock the thread.