# Does it make sense to make expensive syscalls from different goroutines?

Tags: multithreading, go, system-calls, goroutine

If application does some heavy lifting with multiple file descriptors (e.g., opening - writing data - syncing - closing), what actually happens to Go runtime? Does it block all the goroutines at the time when expensive syscall occures (like `syscall.Fsync`)? Or only the calling goroutine is blocked while the others are still operating?

So does it make sense to write programs with multiple workers that do a lot of user space - kernel space context switching? Does it make sense to use multithreading patterns for disk input?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

var data = []byte("some big data")

func worker(filenamechan chan string, wg *sync.waitgroup) {
    defer wg.done()
    for {
        filename, ok := <-filenamechan
        if !ok {
            return
        }

        // open file is a quite expensive operation due to
        // the opening new descriptor
        f, err := os.openfile(filename, os.o_create|os.o_wronly, os.filemode(0644))
        if err != nil {
            log.fatal(err)
            continue
        }

        // write is a cheap operation,
        // because it just moves data from user space to the kernel space
        if _, err := f.write(data); err != nil {
            log.fatal(err)
            continue
        }

        // syscall.fsync is a disk-bound expensive operation
        if err := f.sync(); err != nil {
            log.fatal(err)
            continue
        }

        if err := f.close(); err != nil {
            log.fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    // launch workers
    filenamechan := make(chan string)
    wg := &sync.waitgroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        wg.add(1)
        go worker(filenamechan, wg)
    }

    // send tasks to workers
    filenames := []string{
        "1.txt",
        "2.txt",
        "3.txt",
        "4.txt",
        "5.txt",
    }
    for i := range filenames {
        filenamechan <- filenames[i]
    }
    close(filenamechan)

    wg.wait()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/O0omcPBMAJ

Comment: Related: [Number of threads used by Go runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245660/number-of-threads-used-by-go-runtime/39246575#39246575).

Comment: Also asked and being discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/NXMTsgZ_In8/discussion).

Answer (score 4):

If a syscall blocks, the Go runtime will launch a new thread so that the number of threads available​ to run goroutines remains the same.

A fuller explanation can be found here: https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler