# How can I perform a non-blocking write on a net.Conn?

Tags: networking, go, nonblocking

How can I perform a non-blocking write on a network connection in Go?

I thought it might be possible to do so by setting the deadline in the past:

```
conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, time.UTC))
n, err := conn.Write(buffer)
```

... but this just fails with an 'i/o timeout' error without actually writing any bytes to the connection.

Comment: You don't. That's sort of the point of goroutines. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also that deadline is far in the past, so it times out immediately. Did you mean `time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second)`?

Comment: @JimB: Non-blocking writes in a one-thread-at-a-time (bytecode-like) interpreter.  If the write would block I will either inform or suspend the thread (and allow another to run).  I can do non-blocking writes to a channel, so I can achieve what I want indirectly by having a dedicated goroutine for each socket to schlep the bytes from a channel to the socket, but that seems like a stupid amount of extra overhead (and complexity) to do something that ought to be very straight forward.

Comment: @cpcallen: goroutines are not threads, and a blocked write to a network does not block an entire thread. I don't know what the "stupid amount of extra overhead" you're referring to is.

Comment: @Adrian: No; stopping the world for one second is not acceptable - and attempting to tune the timeout to be as small as possible risks having writes that would not block fail unnecessarily.

Comment: It doesn't stop the world, only the current goroutine.

Comment: @JimB: I am aware that blocked goroutines do not tie up OS threads; the threads I refer to are threads of execution in the language I am implementing.  Re: overhead: there are two kinds: the conceptual complexity of managing the per-socket goroutines and reporting back to the interpreted code which writes ultimately succeeded/failed;  additionally the performance hit of otherwise unnecessary channel reads/writes + associated data copying and scheduling.  (Performance is likely a non-issue for my use case, but were I writing some kind of high-performance web server I might think otherwise.)

Comment: @Adrian: The language I'm implementing has a co-operative multitasking model, with only a single thread running at a time.  The interpreter runs in a single goroutine; if this blocks it cannot run another thread instead.  (I could have a goroutine per interpreted-language thread, but this would require extensive synchronisation to ensure that only one such interpreter goroutine could run at a time, to avoid violating language semantics.  This would also require some non-trivial changes to the overall architecture of the interpreter.)

Comment: In trying to write an interpreter in Go for a language that behaves very unlike Go, you're likely to run into these kinds of obstacles on a regular basis; the mismatch will cause things like this, which are trivial in Go, to become bigger headaches. And if you were writing a high-performance web server, I'd hope you would learn from Node's mistakes and not make it single-threaded!

Answer (score 3):

In Go you use blocking I/O and the runtime "converts" it to non-blocking I/O: a goroutine blocked while reading from a socket, will be swapped by the scheduler with another goroutine ready to continue its execution.

Thus, you get the best of both worlds: code that's easier to follow (eg. no callback hell) *and* the efficiency of non-blocking I/O (ie. epoll, kqueue, completion ports).

**UPDATE:**

> @cpcallen *I need to be able to write to a socket in such a way that I can be certain that the thread performing the write does not block.*

If by "thread" you refer the OS-level thread, it is not blocked. If by "thread" you refer to the goroutine performing the write, that's not yet possible but there's a proposal: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15735

Comment: I need to be able to write to a socket in such a way that I can be certain that the thread performing the write does not block.

Comment: @cpcallen Updated my answer addressing your comment.

Comment: yes: in my comment I said thread but meant goroutine.  Good spot with issues/15735, but I think that's blocking without reading, rather than writing without blocking...

Comment: @Agis referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685437/if-goroutines-involve-userspace-threads-can-a-blocking-operation-leads-to-conte) when you call a blocking syscall the goroutine and os-level thread blocked.