# Why are there more OS threads when running go simple app?

Tags: multithreading, go

When running a simple app, there are **more OS threads** than the max allowed by my processor.

This is the sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
        "time"
)

func doSomething() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Minute)
}

func main() {
        maxProcs := runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0)
        numCPU := runtime.NumCPU()
        fmt.Println(maxProcs) // -> Prints 8
        fmt.Println(numCPU) // -> Prints 8
        for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
                go doSomething()
        }
        time.Sleep(20 * time.Minute)
}
```

Then, when running:

```
go build main.go
./main
```

I can see **more than 8 OS threads related with the process**:

```
ps -T 15419
    PID    SPID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  15419   15419 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15420 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15421 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15422 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15423 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15424 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15425 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15426 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15427 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15428 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15429 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
  15419   15430 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 ./main
```

As far as I know, I should expect upto 8 OS Threads only. Why do I get more than that?
Thanks!

**Edit #2**:
It seems I had a wrong understanding of `time.Sleep`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527705/will-time-sleep-block-goroutine) explains that *Sleep is blocking*, so the new OS Threads are expected.

**Edit #1**:
Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand that, following  [pkg.go.dev/runtime](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime) documentation:

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

There should be 8 OS threads only for this application

Comment: "I should expect upto 8 OS Threads only." Why?

Comment: @Volker, the accepted answer of Woody1193 has pointed me to the my wrong understanding of OS threads. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527705/will-time-sleep-block-goroutine). Essentially, `time.Sleep` blocks the go routine so it allows you to have more than `GOMAXPROCS` goroutines running so long as the number of active threads does not exceed this value. Since `doSomething` just sleeps for 10 minutes and then exits, all 200 calls to it effectively don't contribute to this value at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The related question explains a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please note the statement 'execute user-level Go code' in

> The GOMAXPROCS variable limits the number of operating system threads
> that can execute user-level Go code simultaneously. There is no limit
> to the number of threads that can be blocked in system calls on behalf
> of Go code; those do not count against the GOMAXPROCS limit.

besides user-level go code, there is Go runtime need to run.

if you make a core dump to your go application, you will see there are several goroutines, some of them is used for garbage collection, some of them is blocked on system call, one of them is runtime scheduler, some of them is IO wait, etc.

the relationship between goroutine and system thread is a complex topic. I can only tell you that besides user-level go code, there is go runtime which definitely need system thread to perform their work.